Variation reduction about law of large numbers
Suppose that $X_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$.
Let $\varphi$ be a $\{0,1\}$-valued measurable function on $\mathbb R$, with $\mathbb E[\varphi(X_0)] \in (0,1)$. By law of large numbers, it follows that
$$
  \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\varphi(X_i) = \mathbb E[\varphi(X_0)], ~a.s.
$$
Then I want to ask if there exists a sequence of $\{0,1\}$-valued measurable functions $\varphi_i$ on $\mathbb R$ such that
$$
  \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\varphi_i(X_i) = \mathbb E[\varphi(X_0)], ~a.s.,
~
\lim_{n \to \infty}\varphi_i(X_i) = \varphi(X_0)~\mbox{in distribution}.
$$
and for some $n_0$, and any $n \ge n_0$, it holds that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\varphi_i(X_i) \ge \mathbb E[\varphi(X_0)]$.



My thought: whether we can prove a weaker conclusion first in the sense that
the constraint
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\varphi_i(X_i) \ge \mathbb E[\varphi(X_0)]$
is relaxed to $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\varphi_i(X_i) \ge \mathbb E[\varphi(X_0)] - \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.
From central limit theory, even in the relaxed case, there is no gurantee of some $n_0$, such that for $n \ge n_0$, the constraint
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\varphi(X_i) \ge \mathbb E[\varphi(X_0)] - \varepsilon$
should be true.
This is my motivation to ask the question, if we can change $\varphi$ to let the variation of the average sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n\varphi_i(X_i)$ can be controlled at least on one side.

You might be able to do it if you change the constant $n_0$ into a random variable $N_0$ and allow the result to hold almost surely (rather than surely).

Sorry that the result should be almost surely.

Let me answer the question with the modification that you only require the inequality to hold with probability one.
If you want $n_0$ to be non-random, then no. This is also true without the above modification.
Here is why. Let $I$ be the set of all $i$ such that $\varphi_i$ is a.s. constant equal to $1$. We check by contradiction that $I$ is infinite: assume that $I$ is finite of cardinality $N$; then for every $n$ we have with positive probability $\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(X_i) \leq N$. Taking $n > N/\mathbb E[\phi(X_0)]$ breaks your inequality.
Thus $I$ must be infinite. Let $(n_k)_{k\geq 1}$ be an enumeration of $I$: then $\phi_{n_k}(X_{n_k}) = 1$ a.s., thus $\lim_{k\to\infty} \varphi_{n_k}(X_{n_k}) = 1$ in distribution. This means we do not have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \varphi_i(X_i) = \varphi(X_0)$ in distribution.
Your statement will hold with a random $n_0$, although this is a more delicate question altogether.
